# Python module not recognizing files in the same folder

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, python-module

I've made (at least tried) a package using `setuptools` and attempted to use it from another python-file. However, the modules within the packages don't seem to recognize each other.

Tree

```
pkg
|-- pkg
|     |-- __init__.py
|     \-- module.py
\-- setup.py
```

`__init__.py`:

```
import module
#code
```

`pyfile.py`

```
import pkg
#code
```

When I attempt to run `pyfile.py`, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../py/pyfile.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg
  File "/.../pkg/pkg/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import module
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module'
```

It works fine if I write `import pkg.module`, but I don't see why self.referential code would be practical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the import in your  `__init__` to

```
from . import module
```

You can read more about [intra-package references](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) in the python documentation.

(BTW, as far as I can tell, `setuptools` is not involved here.)

Comment: That is odd. I would expect `import module` to look in its folder.

Comment: I think it's a difference between python 2.7 and python 3.5 (in python 2.7 you can just use import module ...)

Comment: Yes, you are right. The python 2.7 manual says: "The submodules often need to refer to each other. [...] In fact, such references are so common that the import statement first looks in the containing package before looking in the standard module search path." Python 3.5 doen't look in the same package. The above solution, however, works for Python 2 and Python 3.